# Android 13 camera crashes : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) : /vendor/bin/mm-qcamera-daemon

Tags: camera, segmentation-fault, crash, dereference, android-13

In android 13, the camera crashes upon launching. The camera worked perfectly fine in android 12, however, in android 13 it crashes.

I am not sure what is the root cause of the issue. I have attached the tombstones created.

```
**A13 camera crash: tombstone_00: signal 11**
https://gist.github.com/aoleary/9854a12afef5988acc37e81670d688da
**A13 camera crash: tombstone_01: Abort message: ' timed out in posting event.**
https://gist.github.com/aoleary/91b1f10d2f3c153c0640c3ad70c03988
**A13 camera crash: tombstone_02: Cause: null pointer dereference**
https://gist.github.com/aoleary/d22dfec4b2ec9bf0b3b244d39388ddd8
```

Also please find attached the logcat of the camera crashes:
https://gist.github.com/aoleary/c2306c4cb39a631680334f94c5e2a028

Can someone provide me with some tips as to how I would go about analysing the tombstones to find out what is causing the camera to crash ?

```
https://github.com/aoleary/device_lge_g4-common/tree/t4
https://github.com/aoleary/G4-Titan-Kernel/tree/t
https://github.com/aoleary/vendor_lge/tree/t
```

Many thanks for any help provided.

I have tried analysing the logs, but cant read them. Would like help on how to debug the camera crashes.

Comment: Anyone got any suggestions ? At least something I could try to debug the situation